# Randomly select elements in a nested list one time

Tags: python, random

Is there an algorithmic way that I could "randomly" select elements in a nested list, but not make a repeated selection? I am trying to figure out a way to randomly select elements in the nested list only once until all elements have been selected.

This is my nested list:

```
devices = [['radio/36'],
            ['radio/38',
            'radio/31'],
            ['radio/21',
            'radio/29'],
            ['radio/25',
            'radio/9',
            'radio/6'],
            ['radio/13',
            'radio/14',
            'radio/30'],
            ['radio/19',
            'radio/8',
            'radio/26',
            'radio/24'],
            ['radio/34',
            'radio/11',
            'radio/27',
            'radio/20',
            'radio/23'],
            ['radio/15',
            'radio/37',
            'radio/39',
            'radio/10']]
```

For example there is nothing in the code below that will prevent selecting or printing something twice.

```
import random

for i in range(len(devices)):
    random_pick = devices[random.randint(0, len(devices))]
    print(random_pick)
```

The code above is definitely lacking a lot and has the potential to print something twice or completely miss an element.

```
['radio/19', 'radio/8', 'radio/26', 'radio/24']
['radio/38', 'radio/31']
['radio/19', 'radio/8', 'radio/26', 'radio/24']
['radio/36']
['radio/36']
['radio/15', 'radio/37', 'radio/39', 'radio/10']
['radio/36']
['radio/36']
```

Comment: That's not a dictionary... It's a `list` of `list`s. Are you just looking for `random.sample`?

Comment: Shoot thats typo I definitely meant lists ill fix

Comment: use `random.shuffle()` to reorder the array randomly.

Comment: Do you want to pick single items out of the sublist too?

Comment: My idea is to call through each sublist one time randomly like in a `range` loop format

Comment: You're not selecting anything from the nested lists. You're just selecting elements of the top-level list.

Comment: The fact that the list elements are other lists is irrelevant to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - What @Barmar said in the comments

Using [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) would be a pretty simple way of iterating through your list in a random order.

```
import random


def main():
    devices = [
        ['radio/36'],
        ['radio/38', 'radio/31'],
        ['radio/21', 'radio/29'],
        ['radio/25', 'radio/9', 'radio/6'],
        ['radio/13', 'radio/14', 'radio/30'],
        ['radio/19', 'radio/8', 'radio/26', 'radio/24'],
        ['radio/34', 'radio/11', 'radio/27', 'radio/20', 'radio/23'],
        ['radio/15', 'radio/37', 'radio/39', 'radio/10']
    ]
    random.shuffle(devices)

    for device in devices:
        print(device)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: this appears to work I think I can work with this. Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably use `random.sample` or copy the list as to not perturb its original order.

Comment: as long as the "sub lists" don't change (radio ID numbers in each sub list) the order doesn't matter at all for what I am using it for.

Comment: Ill have to experiment the difference between random.sample and shuffle thanks again ill hit the green check soon